# Should I use provider for separation of widget to be reusable?

Tags: flutter

I am beginner who is learning about flutter. I am confused about using provider package for state management.Is it needed to use when there are changes of widgets from outside? For my problem, I build and separate Custom Login Widget which extends StatelessWidget to be reusable and call this custom widget from another which extends StatefulWidget. Login Form has specific validations for User Input and some changes of UI like normalizing User Input so that all actions and validations are made in StatefulWidget class and use setState function when there are changes for displaying validation message for custom Login widget.I am not clear the way I am using is correct or not.Should I apply provider for these situations or not? Please advice me and how to do.